# Initializing std::vector with a single value - repetitive or push_back()?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, constructor, std

I have a (virtual) function which returns a `std::vector` with a single value. Let's assume the class looks like:

```
#include <vector>

class Z; // irrelevant

class C
{
    Z& something;

public:
    typedef std::vector<Z*> list_type;

    virtual list_type f();
};
```

Is it better to use the repetitive constructor:

```
C::list_type C::f()
{
    return list_type(1, &something);
}
```

or just `push_back()` the single element:

```
C::list_type C::f()
{
    list_type ret;

    ret.push_back(&something);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: define "better"? The first is one line of code - that gets my vote!

Comment: 1st option is any day better.

Comment: @Nim: if I could, I would do that already. I'm just wondering what are pros and cons of these two options.

Comment: @MichałGórny, don't get it, `std::vector` support just such a constructor! `explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T()...)`

Comment: I meant 'if I could define "better"'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider "better" to be "short code", then probably the repetitive constructor is better because is shorter and therefore more concise.

In terms of functionality, both are equal.

In terms of performance, the repetitive constructor can be better because it can call `reserve()` as it knows beforehand the total number of elements that it's going to allocate. However, you are using it just to create an element, so I guess it does not matter.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about `reserve()` as well. Is it likely that when using `push_back()`, the vector may actually reserve more space than when using repetitive constructor? The derived classes will likely override this method and push back more elements into the vector.

Comment: I don't think you should rely on this information, provided it could be obtained. I mean, probably that is dependant on an implementation detail, i.e., it is not standardized. You can only count on push_back() being constant (amortized) and the repetitive constructor, linear. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/

Comment: @MichałGórny The key question is whether you know at the base class how many elements the derived classes will insert. If you cannot know that, then using `reserve()` does not make too much sense. If you have that information, though, then even if it is implementation-defined, using `reserve()` will not be worse than using N times `push_back` (and it can actually be better).

Answer (score 2):

They are basically equivalent in terms of functionality, but `return list_type(1, &something);` might be more efficient since you directly pre-allocate the vector to its desired capacity, plus you avoid a call to `push_back`.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler is new enough to handle C++11 [initializer lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists) you could use that to say:

```
C::list_type C::f()
{
    return list_type{&something};
}
```

Comment: My goal is C++98 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using repetitive form is better since `vector` then would allocate precisely `N` elements, initializing them with given value (as compared to reallocating underlying array for `log2(N)` times, which will happen in case of repetitive `push_back()`'s).

But in case of just one pointer, the difference is negligible; and using `-O3` or whatever will probably turn these constructions into the same assembly code.